# How To get the Size of files and Folder size using python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to get the list of all files, with size per file and total size of folder. If the directory contains "A" as root, under A we have subdirectories B,C,D, and under those subdirectories have some files and again folders under that some files.

I have used the below code using python to get the size. I'm able to get the size of each file of folder and sub folder and finally the total size of root folder. But I'm not able to get subfolders total size before the root total size.

Can someone help me on this issue?

```
import os
folder_path = "/Apath/"
def GetTotalFolderSize(path):
  folder_size = 0
  file_size=0
  for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
     for file in files:
        path1=os.path.join(path, file)
        file_size = os.path.getsize(os.path.join(path, file))
        print("filename: "+path1+" , "+ "size: ",file_size)
        filename = os.path.join(path, file)
        folder_size += os.path.getsize(filename)

  return folder_size
Total_size=GetTotalFolderSize(folder_path)
print("Totalsize of folder:"+folder_path,Total_size)
```

Getting output as: B1 filename size=120,B2 filename size=150,c1 filename size=100 and...,total size=370

Comment: If you want to "to get subfolders total size before the root total size.", why not simply add an if-conditional to add the sizes of all subdirectories, but exclude the one of the root folder? Also, in a more generalized solution you'd have to consider things such as, broken symlinks, cyclical symlinks etc etc

Comment: Thanks hyper TrashPanda, I'm getting the subfolder-subsubfolder total size.But subfolder total size not getting. i have used folder_size=0 inside of first for loop. Getting total size of sub-subfolder size but subfolder size not.Can you please help me on this